# Simple telnetlib.Telnet not working. Connection Refused Error

Tags: python, telnet

I have a simple script that is failing.  I am running the service and the firewall is off.  Anyone have any ideas on what's wrong? I can't netcat to it either with cmd : `nc -vz 127.0.0.1 40400`

Python 2.7

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("127.0.0.1", 40400)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mhegglin/assignments/telemetry/Basis.py", line 3, in 
>       tn = telnetlib.Telnet("127.0.0.1", 40400)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py",
>   line 211, in **init**
>       self.open(host, port, timeout)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py",
>   line 227, in open
>       self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
>
> File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py",
>   line 575, in create_connection
>       raise err socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

My telnet server wasn't staying online so when I tried to telnet it was failing